# How to list all shortcuts that are on the android home app

Tags: android

I need to find a way to delete no longer valid shortcuts to my app from the home activity. Can't completely reproduce the intent that is used to create the shortcut so I need the list of all home shortcuts in order to recognize the one that I need to delete.

Answer (score 1):

You most likely won't be able to do that. Shortcuts are managed by launcher and unless one of your choice exposes this information, you simply won't be able to get it.